# What is difference between geth, myEtherWallet and etherscan

Tags: blockchain, metamask, myetherwallet

I am new to blockchain technology and learning it, there are many terms of blockchain which confused me like geth client, meta mask, etherscan and myEtherWaller.
I used geth it's a ethereum client to create a blockchain network.

Comment: Geth client is an Ethereum Node application, MyEtherWallet is a web service which uses Ethereum Nodes in order to allow users to write data into the blockchain and to read data from the blockchain, Etherscan is similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- MyEtherWallet, MyCrypto etc. are wallet interfaces. They are the link between you and the blockchain. They don't store any sensitive information like private keys themselves.
- MetaMask is similar to a wallet interface, but it also provides decentralised applications (secure) access to your account.
- Geth, Parity, is software to run your own Ethereum node. By doing that, your pc or server becomes part of the network. Wallet interfaces like MyCrypto run their own Geth or Parity nodes to provide you access.
- Etherscan is a block explorer, it keeps track of everything that's happening on the blockchain and shows it in a human readable way.

Comment: It mean thru MyEtherWaller you connect with blockchain network which is not running in your PC ? ( mean geth client or parity services running on any different machine ? )

Comment: Yes, wallet interfaces run their own blockchain nodes/servers that you can connect to, usually Geth or Parity.